# Font size for appImages

Tags: 18.10, appimage

Im using 2 appImages vlc and kdenlive. Both do not respect my global font settings and the fonts in the apps are really tiny and I can't read them. Does anyone know how to make them follow my global settings in Ubuntu or how to set their config files directly. Thanks